# Calculate VAT in shopping cart

Tags: angular, typescript

i am building a webshop for a pizzeria in Angular and just finished my cart component.
I implemented a cart service and now want to add a 10% VAT for each item and add it to my total.

in my cart service  i defined calcTotal and the necessary operations.

```
calcTotal() {
    let total: number = 0;
    let service: number = 0;

    this.cart.forEach((val) => {
      service = val.price * 0.1;
      total += val.price + service;
      total
    })
    return total;
  }
```

I added the properties to my cart.component.ts

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  cart: Imenu[] = [];
  total: number = 0;
  service: number = 0;


  constructor(private CS: CartService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cart = this.CS.getCart();
    this.total = this.CS.calcTotal();
    this.service = this.CS.calcTotal();


  }
}
```

In my cart.component.html I am printing the service and total value,

```
 <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 order-md-last">
        <p>Service: {{service}}</p>
        <p>Total: {{total}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

service and total both print the same value.

How to declare service in my cart.service.ts so that it prints as 10% of my total?

Answer (score 0):

`service` are using the same `calcTotal` method that returns the `total` value only.

Either you can write another method to calculate the total VAT.

```
calcServiceTotal() {
  let serviceTotal: number = 0;

  this.cart.forEach((val) => {
    serviceTotal += val.price * 0.1;
  });

  return serviceTotal;
}
```

```
this.service = this.CS.calcServiceTotal();
```

---

Or implement the `calTotal` method to return both `service` and `total` values.

```
calcTotal() {
  let total: number = 0;
  let serviceTotal: number = 0;

  this.cart.forEach((val) => {
    service = val.price * 0.1;
    serviceTotal += service;
    total += val.price + service;
  });

  return [serviceTotal, total];
}
```

And use the [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign values to both `service` and `total`.

```
[this.service, this.total] = this.CS.calcTotal();
```

Note that you may see the result as: 3.1200000003. You may refer to this question: [Why does 0.1 + 0.2 return unpredictable float results in JavaScript while 0.2 + 0.3 does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778431/why-does-0-1-0-2-return-unpredictable-float-results-in-javascript-while-0-2).

Thus, it is recommended to use [`DecimalPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) to display the decimals in format.

```
<p>Service: {{service | number}}</p>
<p>Total: {{total | number}}</p>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rqxrlo?file=src%2Fmain.ts)